# setBackgroundColor is deprecated

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a view item in my RecyclerAdapter's onBindViewHolder. Since setBackgroundColor is deprecated, what should I do instead?

```
holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(bgColor));
```

Comment: just checked the View docs itemView is field in viewHolder using the View you passed and in View setBackgroundcolor is not depreciated.

Comment: getColor is still deprecated, even in that context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `getResources().getColor(bgColor)` is depracated

Use below one

```
ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.bgcolor)
```

Comment: But how does that work in relation to the view holder? I don't think this is a duplicate question. The answer doesn't solve the problem. ``holder.itemView.ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.bgColor);`` doesn't work. See what I mean?

Comment: holder.itemview.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.bgColor)); This will be your code

Comment: @santafebound if it helps you can I get an upvote as well